# How to add extension at end

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

How can i add .JPG at end of all the serial number (001,002,003).

```
C:\Users\Abc\Desktop\id card 10-12-19\001.jpg
C:\Users\Abc\Desktop\id card 10-12-19\002.jpg
```

Is there any way to add the extension at the end (.jpg), I would suggest how it work in both i.e Microsoft Excel and Google spreed sheet. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="";;A1:A&".jpg"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
=query(arrayformula(B21:B &".jpg"), "Select * where Col1<>'.jpg'")
```

in this formula I use query and array formula, and I put the formula in C21, the data populated in range all in column B begin from B21.

```
= arrayformula(B21:B &".jpg")
```

mean all row in column B begin from B21 will be given by ".jpg"

```
=query(arrayformula(B21:B &".jpg"), "Select * where Col1<>'.jpg'")
```

Only return from resul of array formula, just if in column B have string (not blank)

Comment: Can you please add more detail to your answer? In its current state, it's unlikely to help future readers.